# how to make a chrome extension with Metro UI CSS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to implement a Metro UI for my chrome extension. I just use the page control sample code as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample</title>
  <link href="css/modern.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/dropdown.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src= "javascript/pagecontrol.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="metrouicss">
  <div class="page-control" data-role="page-control">
        <!-- Responsive controls -->
        <span class="menu-pull"></span> 
        <div class="menu-pull-bar"></div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#frame1">Frame1</a></li>
            ...
            <li><a href="#frameN">FrameN</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tabs content -->
        <div class="frames">
            <div class="frame active" id="frame1"> ...frame content... </div>
            ...
            <div class="frame" id="frameN"> ...frame content... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it's fine if I open the popup.html in my web browser:
[image]

but it looks weird if I open it in chrome extension:
[image]

I don't know how to fix it and I'm new to make a html application. Maybe this is a quite simple question, but please help me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you render HTML on a standard web browser window it will stretch to fill the width of the page, unless the markup instructs otherwise. When you attempt to transpose this into a Chrome Popup window it will get squished into the default popup box size.

What you need to do here is explicitly define a width on the div that wraps around all your other content. Try something like this

```
 <div class="page-control" data-role="page-control" style="width:600px;">
 ...
 ...
 </div>
```

Perhaps the css class `page-control` has some width already defined in the CSS but I can't see the full CSS path as it's not exposed on your code sample. Regardless, the explicitly defined width above will override it.